# Does any change in my code cause problem in client's code?

Tags: java

I provide an interface for client's code. And one day I changed the return value of the interface class (Java).

```
public Response getReponse(Input info){
    ....

    return response;
}

class Response {
    private String name;

    // newly added field
    private String source;
}
```

My client doesn't care about this new field, and the new filed 'source' doesn't affect the behavior of the client code. Now if I re-publish my API without updating a new release number, is that ok if the client doesn't update to the new API, or it will break?

Comment: Changing the API and not changing the release number is probably a bad idea. How does the client interact with the server? Is it by using your code directly or is there a remote call (eg. via HTTP / REST) in between?

Comment: It is better to ask client to update to the new API I think (I am not very sure since I don't have a lot of experience myself) ... good question though

Comment: Please edit your title to be more specific about a particular technical issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say whether what you are proposing to do will break anything<sup>1</sup>.

If the `source` field is just a private field, then it is not part of the API.  Taken in isolation, adding a new private field should be an invisible implementation change.

On the other hand, if there are getters or setters, then this could affect the client.   Adding getters and setters doesn't break binary compatibility, but you could still get odd effects:

- This could break `ObjectOutputStream` serializations due to serial version ID mismatches.
- This could break serialization, DI, etc code that uses reflection to look at private fields.
- This may lead to unexpected behavior.  For example, if someone has created a subclass of your `Response` "interface" which already implements a `source` field, then the `Response` subclass now has two separate `source` fields.  And you / your client may get accidental overriding or even compilation errors.

Then there is the issue that your customers may actually be using your wire protocol.  So adding a new element could break their code.  Is your protocol itself versioned?

Then again, if this is *your* client code and *your* server code, and you control the entire software and deployment base (i.e. *all* clients and servers), then what you do with version numbering is entirely up to you.  You just get to deal with all of the consequences :-)

---

My advice would be to analyze your problem a lot more carefully.  Think through all of the potential issues *for yourself*.

By the way, if there are other people (programmers, users) who could be impacted, it is not *just* a matter of bumping a version number.  You also need to document the change for anyone who might be affected.  Especially for people who may need (or want!) to change *their* code.

---

<sup>1 - For instance, it is unclear if your use of the word "client" means "one of my paying customers" or a software in the "client" role in a client-server interaction!</sup>

Comment: It's a piece of software.

Comment: Well ... you say "client's" code ... and an English apostrophe in that context indicates possession.  So you may want to correct your Question.